# How to return HTML within an Object using React and SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to show an image using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) within the text field. I do believe SweetAlert just returns and object. This is what it looks like:

```
swal({
  title: 'Title',
  text: 'text',
  type: 'success'
})
```

Each of these normally take a string. What I want to do is show and image within the text field. I tried doing `text: (<img src="image_src" />)` , but this did not work, it just shows `[ojbect Object]` in the alert.

I should of noted this but I also am putting in a variable inside the src for the image. So I need this to work somehow

```
<img src={`${image_url}`} />
```

Please let me know if you need anymore code!

Comment: Use `html` instead of `text`: https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/#custom-html

Comment: So you have to use html with quotes? because I have to put a variable in the code like so `<img src={\`${image_url}\`} />`

Comment: It takes objects with html nodes as children, too. Take a look at the source: https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/blob/master/src/sweetalert2.js#L68-L87

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the helpful comments from @helb I found out instead of using

```
swal({
  title: 'Title',
  text: 'text',
  type: 'success'
})
```

I need to do this instead:

```
swal({
  title: 'Title',
  html: `<img src='${image_url}'/>`,
  type: 'success'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content'

const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal)
MySwal.fire({
title: 'Title',
html: `<img src='${image_url}'/>`,
type: 'success'
})
```

https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).